# import app name into project urls.py Django

Tags: python, django

I am building django app using python IDLE on Windows, how can I import app module into the urls.py?

Because if I directly use the app name , e.g. accounts.urls, it gives me the error: name "accounts" is not difined.

The urls.py file is like:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('account/',accounts.urls),
```

]

And I do have app "accounts" in the INSTALLED_APP in settings.py. 
Do I need to import the app into the urls.py file?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your application `accounts`, provide `__init__.py` (at least empty one) is in the directory `accounts`, then import it as usual and add to paths.

`accounts` has to be listed in your `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`.

Your layout will be

```
|
+--accounts
|         |
|         +__init__.py
|         |
|         +urls.py
|
+--your_project
|         |
|         +urls.py -- this is where you `import accounts`
|         |
|         +wsgi.py
+--manage.py
```

So your resulting code in urls.py will be

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
import accounts 

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('account/',accounts.urls),
]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed reply. I follow your guidance and check the project structure, it seems it is just the case you mentioned. So is it anything else I might be missing?

Comment: The `import accounts` statement was missing at the top of  `urls.py`. Other than that should be fine. You're welcome.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Finally I noticed that I should use "path('account/',include('account.urls')"  .   Your reply is helpful to me as well.